# How to see Oracle Table Logs?

Tags: database, oracle, logging

I look at a table's properties in Oracle and it has "LOGGING: YES". How can I query that log, or if it's in a file, where can I find it?

Comment: What are you trying to see? When logging is enabled, all operations against that table are logged. If you need to recover after an instance failure Oracle will use the logs to restore the database by applying changes since the last backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging on a table just means that all DML on the table will generate REDO, eg, if the server crashes the table will be recoverable. If you have LOGGING turned off, then some types of DML (direct load) will not cause redo, and may not be recoverable after a crash.

This option is something that you would mainly use in a data warehouse I believe.

A good article on it can be found [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3631361/Managing-Tables-Logging-versus-Nologging.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo Matthew's reply, but also add that you can sort-of query the "log" by using the Flashback Query syntax. You're really querying the undo rather than the redo, of course, and performance is nothing spectacular. 11g has significant enhancements.

Comment: True. I don't /think/ thats what the OP meant though, I assume he was after "what are the last 10 queries run on the table"

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn Auditing on. That can audit INS/UPD/DEL/SEL both successes and/or failures. It can write the results to a table or to the file system.